# how to hide login page after login by facebook in android app

Tags: android

I am login in my android app through facebook login.I am going to login successfully in my app. but problem is that after login ,login screen is coming again as follow.[image]

And after click on cross symbol on left top ,it is hiding login screen and login successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For that use SharedPreferences class for that.

Ex. Create SharedPreferences class.

public class SharedPreferencesUtility {

```
SharedPreferences sharedpref;

public SharedPreferencesUtility(Context context) {

    sharedpref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

public void setVerifiy(boolean b) {

    sharedpref.edit().putBoolean("isVerify", b).commit();
}

public boolean getVerifiy() {

    return sharedpref.getBoolean("isVerify", false);
}
```

}

use the method ***setVerifiy*** true when you login through facebook and after the check method ***getVerifiy*** in splash/Other activity oncreate method.

```
  private Activity activity;
  private SharedPreferencesUtility preferencesUtility;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    activity = SplashActivity.this;

    preferencesUtility = new SharedPreferencesUtility(activity);

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (preferencesUtility.getVerifiy()) {

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class));

                finish();

            } else {

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginPage.class));

                finish();

            }

        }
    }, 3000);
}
```